# settings.gradle & java_home

Tags: android, android-studio

hello i have error  i fix java home & dsk & flutter but still have this error

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\ArmutDz\Desktop\source_code\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\ArmutDz.gradle\caches\6.7.1\scripts\3s4zrcnurrt8mcmjlw7xg5wwp).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 61

i have version Flutter 3.0.2 • channel stable & Tools • Dart 2.17.3 • DevTools 2.12.2

what wrong please help